# str.replace к списку столбцов pd.df

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Как применить к списку столбцов (не к заголовкам, а к значениям столбцов!) пандас датафрейма функцию `str.replace(',', '.')`. Например: пусть `numeric` - это список всех числовых полей, где надо заменить запятую на точку чтобы потом сработало преобразование `astype('float')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1,23', '3,45'], 'col2': ['1,23', '3,45'], 'col3': ['aaa', 'bbb']})
numeric = ['col1', 'col2']
df[numeric] = df[numeric].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',', '.')).astype('float64')
print(df)
```

```
   col1  col2 col3
0  1.23  1.23  aaa
1  3.45  3.45  bbb
```